# IIS Symfony 4, 404 Error

Tags: symfony, iis, web-config

I am trying to make works symfony 4 demo application on my environemnt.
I am using IIS with CGI and rewrite module. I can't have access to the home page of the demo, I think my IIS configuration is not well configured. Is there a standard web.config for symfony 4 and IIS? I didn't find anything.

Comment: From the vendor page, they don't support running on IIS. Ping their support resources, as without an official answer, it would be almost impossible for you to port it to IIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally make it works. I convert the rewrite rules of the htaccess to IIS xml.
It looks like below. Hoping it will help others.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```